# C# SQLiteとDataGridViewを関連付ける方法

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

お世話になります。

VisualStudioC#2015Expressにて、既存のSQLiteデータベースを
フォームに張り付けたDataGridViewで表示したり、編集したり
したいのですが、上手くいきません。当然、DataGridViewの内容を
変更すれば、コードで書かなくてもDBが変更される仕様です。

『データベースエクスプローラー』のツリーを右クリックして、『接続の追加』、
データソースの選択画面で、SQLiteが出てきません。

http://monslab.iobb.net/BLOG/?p=2846

↑こちらのサイト様をもとに試してみたのですが、どうやっても
リストに表示されません。

そこで、当然結果は無事関連付けができるまでどうすれば良いのかが
知りたいのですが、ここまで面倒な手順をしなければできないものなのでしょうか。
また、実際に最後まで動かせたわけではないので、ここで選択できるように
なった後で何をすればよいのでしょうか。

ちなみに、SQLiteのバージョン、インストーラーのバージョン、
対象のフレームワークなども確認済みです。

対策方法か、もっと簡単な方法がありましたらご教授ください。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studioのデザイナーで使用するADO.NETのデータプロバイダーは`Machine.config`というPC単位の構成ファイルから参照されており、独自のプロバイダーを追加するためには該当アセンブリをGAC(グローバルアセンブリーキャッシュ)に登録したうえで、`Machine.config`に`DbDataProvider`を追加しなければなりません。
なのでインストーラーを使用してSQLiteプロバイダーを構成する必要がありますが、配布先のPCではSQLiteアセンブリがGACに登録されていない可能性が高いので実行用のライブラリをNuGetから取得しているのだと思います。
なのでリンク先の手順は必要があってやっています。

なおデザイナーに依存しないADO.NET直接使用やEFコードファーストなどの手法を使用する場合はNuGet参照だけでSQLiteを使用することもできます。